# Synchronize Exchange Online / Outlook data to OnPremise Network

Tags: windows, exchange, microsoft-office-365, exchangeonline

I have Exchange Online and the newest Version of Outlook in my company.

For years now we have the following Problem:

We have a lot of Users that have multiple mailboxes, shared and personal ones, set up in one account in their Outlook on their Client. These mailboxes are sometimes pretty big.

Now, when they go on holiday for 2 weeks for example and come back, outlook needs to first sync all these mailboxes, which makes Outlook almost completely unresponsive for at least an hour after the startup.

This now happens more frequently, as many users are in their homeoffice most of the time, but sometimes come back to the office for a day to work here.

I really don't know what to do. Our answer when they call us to tell us their Outlook doesn't work as expected is always "We can't really do anything about that, you just have to wait." - which I really don't like.

Now I had an idea, where I don't know if this is possible:

Can I somehow set up some kind of "Sync Server" on my on-premise system, where it syncs all Outlook Mailboxes on this Server, and the clients get their mails and sync with this local server? That would speed up the process I assume, because it would not use the current internet bandwidth of the whole company, but only the internal network.

If there are any other ideas how to tackle my problem, I would also love to hear them. Thanks a bunch!

Comment: Hi, is there any update? Please check if the below info is helpful to you.

Answer (score 0):

> **strong textCan I somehow set up some kind of "Sync Server" on my on-premise
> system, where it syncs all Outlook Mailboxes on this Server, and the
> clients get their mails and sync with this local server? That would
> speed up the process I assume, because it would not use the current
> internet bandwidth of the whole company, but only the internal
> network.**

Sorry for that i'm not familiar with "Sync Server", however, you could follow the below points to narrow down your problem:

- Do you encounter the same issue if you create a profile with a single
  account and sync data from server?
- Did you encounter the same issue when accessing the primary mailbox
  or another mailbox via OWA(Outlook on the web)
- Did you encounter the same issue if you ran Outlook in safe mode?
- Have your mailboxes reached to their storage limits(**[Mailbox
  storage limits](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/office365/servicedescriptions/exchange-online-service-description/exchange-online-limits#mailbox-storage-limits)**)?
- Try to repair your Outlook application and see if there is any
  difference: **[Repair an Office application](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/repair-an-office-application-7821d4b6-7c1d-4205-aa0e-a6b40c5bb88b)**
- View the connection status between Outlook and Exchange Online via
  **Microsoft Remote Connectivity Analyzer**: **https://testconnectivity.microsoft.com/tests/O365Ola/input**

Besides, here is an official documentation about the possible reasons to cause Outlook freeze for your reference:
**[Outlook not responding error or Outlook freezes when you open a file or send mail](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/outlook/troubleshoot/performance/outlook-not-responding-error-or-outlook-freezes)**